# Lost my non git files from workspace

Tags: git, iterm

I have a directory called workspace under ~/Documents/workspace and, it contains multiple folders. Some of the folders in the workspace directory are cloned from GitHub and some are local directories.

Yesterday, I downloaded iTerm on my Mac (At that point, my terminal was on workspace directory).

After downloading iTerm, Now, I don't have any files inside the local directories (non git directories). Also, modified time of all the non git folders is the same. (Modified times of git folders are not changed)

What might be the cause of losing my files only from non git directories. Is there any way to retrieve my deleted/lost file back?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked before. The answer on the lost files is to restore from your backup. Otherwise, just reproduce them.

Comment: hi, have you tried to ask on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)? though i'm afraid lost files cant be brought back.. unless you have something to recover deleted files. git wont help you much..